Why is this command slow only when it writes to a pipe?
I have a command that I run on macOS that does some work and writes a couple lines of text to stdout. The command takes 0.27 secs to complete execution:
$ time <command>
...
<command>  0.14s user 0.09s system 83% cpu 0.272 total

However, when I pipe the command's output to grep, it takes 10.65 secs to complete.
$ time ( <command> | grep <expression> )
...
( <command> | grep <expression> )  0.13s user 0.11s system 2% cpu 10.65 total

Why is that? And how can I go about speeding it up?
Things I've tried:
If I put the command's output in a file and do:
time ( cat file | grep <expression> )

it finishes in 0.118 secs.
If I do the following:
time ( <command> | cat )

it finishes in 10.57 secs.
I tried using strace on the command, but realized it's not available on macOS.
PS: I don't maintain the command. I just use it.

Interesting. I restart my macbook and the combined command is now fast. time ( command | grep <expression> ) is now 0.84 secs. Lesson learned is periodically reboot my laptop. That said, I'm still interested to know what could be causing pipe performance to degrade proportional with the machine's uptime?
